# Polymer option selected

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

How do I set select option selected in Polymer 1.0?

```
<select id="typeSelect" style="width:100%;" value="{{item.type::change}}">
  <option value="">Choose a type</option>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{types}}" as="type" >
    <option selected?="{{type==item.type}}">{{type}}</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close. Use this.

```
<select id="typeSelect" style="width:100%;" value="{{item.type::change}}">
  <option value="">Choose a type</option>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{types}}" as="type" >
    <option selected$="{{selected(type,"yourtypetocompare")}}">{{type}}</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

Now, add a function in your polymer's element.

```
  selected: function(item, type){
    return type == item.type;
  },
```